# formula to do SUM of column blocks?

Tags: excel

I have a formula that I want to tweak to show me quick sums of spending per vendor. I have a formula that I used to use to show the last duplicate value (vendor name) before the report showed the next one: `=if(a2<>a3,"Last","")` but I want to see if I can tweak that to not spit out a text value, but a sum of all expenses under that vendor.

Say I have `vendor 1` in range `A2:A3`, I want a sum of those expenses in cells `C2:C3` and then do the same for every vendor group change.

is this possible?

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Vendor | Price | Sum |
+--------+-------+-----+
|      1 |    50 |     |
|      1 |    60 | 110 |
|      2 |    50 |     |
|      2 |    10 |     |
|      2 |   500 | 560 |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see sample date, but it sounds like you're looking for `SUMIF`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad ahhhh, so ‘=sumif(a2<>a3)’?

Comment: That's not quite how it works, see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B). For us to give more detail,. we'd need sample data

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Try this, because I'm at work and don't have a way to share. In `A2:A5`, put the text `(Vendor 1)`. In `B2:B5` put `50` in all cells. and then do `50` for `b6:b10` and `(Vendor 2)` in `a6:a10`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad sorry, pressed enter too early, but that should give you the gist of how to quickly test it in column C to show the sum of those ranges in column B based on when the text string of the vendor in column A changes.  You can add a few more scenarios, but just make a few vendor names and have numbers to sum up for each vendor change

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad added a quick table in my post to show the sum column and how I envisioned a formula spitting out a sum right before the next vendor ID pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in C2 and copy down the full length of the data.

```
=IF(A2<>A3,SUM($B$1:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I can't say I exactly understand what's going on in the `SUM` areas, especially with column C, but thanks a ton

Comment: It is keeping a running total in Column B and subtracting what has aready be totaled in column C.